# FlurlHttpException Error while copying content to a stream

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

I am using Flurl to post files to the Rest API server and sometimes, 1 in 100 requests, I get an error below. I know that this exception comes from HttpClient and is directly not related to Flur.

```
FlurlHttpException Error while copying content to a stream
```

The question is why I do get this exception?

```
        var fileUploadResultDto = await new Url
        {
            Scheme = ServerSchema,
            Host = ServerHost,
            Path = "upload",
            Port = ServerPort
        }
        .WithHeader("accept", "application/json")
        .WithHeader("content-type", MimeMapping.MimeUtility.GetMimeMapping(fileName))
        .WithHeader("content-disposition", new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "file",
            FileName = fileName,
            FileNameStar = fileName
        })
        .PostAsync(new FileContent(file.FullName))
        .ReceiveJson<FileUploadResultDto>()
    ;
```

Comment: Check the InnerException for details. But since it's about 1% of all calls, and if it seems rather random, I suspect implementing retries will cure it. And if you're doing concurrent uploads, try limiting the degree of concurrency, perhaps using a `SemaphoreSlim`.

Comment: @ToddMenier Indeed we do concurrent uploads, usually from 3 to 10 files at once, how this could be related to the issue?

Comment: Because 1 in 100 seems transient and those types of errors are always more common the harder you're hitting a server. You're right that it's not coming directly from Flurl, it's a fairly [common issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Error+while+copying+content+to+a+stream%22+site:stackoverflow.com) with no clear silver-bullet solution other than implementing backoff-and-retry.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/346531/sporadic-systemnethttphttprequestexception-error-w.html) is a good example. The exception (InnerException in Flurl's case) should have more details, such as "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" in this example. The answer speculates that it basically amounts to a server hiccup. Again, retries should solve this. Have a look at [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).